# What is the relationship between EFS file system policy and mount targets w.r.t. securing EFS?

Tags: amazon-efs

I am looking to securing an EFS file system against unauthorised access. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/access-control-block-public-access.html) article states that:

> When evaluating whether a file system allows public access, Amazon EFS assumes that the file system policy is public. It then evaluates the file system policy to determine if it qualifies as non-public.

Are Security Groups on EFS mount targets the first line of defence against unauthorised access with file system policies providing a means for more granular access? I am unclear how these concepts work together for securing an EFS file system.